# react-router-dom Switch needs additional div wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using `react`, `react-router-dom` and `redux` to create a simple react application. The `package.json` file contains:

```
...

"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",

...
```

The project structure is as follow:

```
- src
   - components
       - Container
            . index.js
       + Customers
       + Greetings
       . App.js
   - reducers
       . customer.js
   . index.js
   . reducers.js
   . Root.js
```

This is what `index.js` file looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import Root from './Root'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer
)

render(<Root store={ store } />, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

This is also what is my `Root.js` file looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import app component
import App from './components/App'

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)

Root.propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root;
```

And following represents my `App` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

// import pages 
import Container from './Container';
import Greetings from './Greetings';
import Customers from './Customers';


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <div> // <~~ This is where the issue happens
                    <Route path="/" component={ Container }></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ Greetings }></Route>
                    <Route path="/customers" component={ Customers }></Route>
                </div>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is when I use `<Switch />` as a wrapper of `<Route />` tags, it needs an inner `<div />` element, otherwise it will not work. 
It means that if I remove the `<div />` element inside the `<Switch />` and wrap the `<Route />`s directly by `<Switch />` the pages will not be rendered, and also no errors or exception throw in the console.

What is the problem? Am I doing wrong somewhere?
Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

Thanks all for useful comments. Here are some important things to consider:

1. I don't get any error or warning, react script works fine and compiles my code completely.
2. As you mentioned, only the first `<Route>` element of a specific path will be rendered, but when I add a `<div>` element as first level of `<Switch>` element as a wrapper for all `<Route>`s it will work fine. But the problem is I don't need the additional `<div>` element to be rendered. Please consider that I would like the Container component to be rendered in all pages and other components in same path ('/') should be rendered as children of Container.

Comment: Can you share what error you're getting and also share the code for Greetings component? FYI I can see that you've configured '/' root path with 2 components, which will work but the first one will always be returned.

Comment: Can you make a small repro on codesandbox.io or such?

Comment: Made a mock react app from your code and its working without extra `div`, take a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/n9nqjvr1vm. Please explain your error in more details with some stack trace if possible, or if you can upload your whole code base to some public repo.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora I've configured '/' root path with 2 components, because I'd like the first one to be rendered in all pages. It would be my container.

Comment: Thanks. But you have just removed the <Provider /> and used only one <Route /> inside the <Switch /> which means it will return the only Route tag and works well. But the problem is when I need to have 2 components for a specific path @RaghavGarg

Comment: RaghavGarg just did it @AftabKhan

Comment: So interesting... When I use a <div> as first level inside the <Switch> tag, it will return all components in same path. But when I remove <div> it will only work with first component of each path. But please consider I would like the Container component to be rendered in all pages and other components in same path ('/') should be rendered as children of Container. @ShobhitChittora

Comment: I have updated the link to accommodate multiple routes but still not using `Provider`. Also, I would like for you to consider this snippet for the problem you are facing for wrapping everything in `Container`. https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/1ad1eb6a8b61c97e6f107c8c2917fff1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. The solution which Raghav mentioned in comments:
   It could be done by making the first `<Route />` -which I need to be rendered in all pages- as a container component and use it as a wrapper of other `<Route />` inside the `<Switch >` tag.  [Gist link from @Raghav](https://gist.github.com/raghavgarg1257/1ad1eb6a8b61c97e6f107c8c2917fff1)

```html
<Switch>
    <Container>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ Greetings }></Route>
        <Route path="/customers" component={ Customers }></Route>
    </Container>
</Switch>
```

2. The second and a newer solution to this problem is using `<React.Fragment>` tag which is available in newer versions of React. `<React.Fragment>` will help you to wrap multiple elements in your component instead of using real html tags. 
   It will not render any extra elements into page

~~> [Link to React documentation for Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)